# wordpress rewrite rule for images from old domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Basically, I want a htaccess rule to rewrite `http://olddomain.com/sitename/wp-content/uploads/.../image.jpg` in `http://www.newdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/.../image.jpg`

Notice the "sitename" in old domain url which is nor present in the new domain url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of olddomain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^sitename/(wp-content/uploads/.+\..+)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: I don't have access to old domain anymore

Comment: If you don't have access to it then how can you redirect any URL from olddomain?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but may satisfy your needs. If you need to convert a bunch of URLs within your WordPress database that are pointing to an old domain name, try [Search-Replace-DB](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB) by interconnectit.

It will run through your database and can replace one domain name with another.

Usual caveats apply: backup your database first, run tests on a development installation, etc. But I've used it and found it performed flawlessly.